# Realizing timeline on mypage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

1.What I want to do.

I would like to show the messages posted in the groups, which a user already joined, on his or her timeline.as This includes the messages posted by other users as long as they are the group mates of his or her.

2.What I did.

(show.html.erb-members)

```
<h1>Mypage</h1>
 <div id="timeline">
  <%= @timelines.each do |tl|%>
   <div class="message_area">
   <p class= "member_name"><a href="/members/<%= tl.member %>">
   <%= tl.member.name %></a></p>
   <p class="message_content"><%= tl.content %></p>
   <p class="message_create">(<%= tl.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
   </p></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

(members.controller.erb)

```
def show
  if !checklogin? then return end
   @me = me?
   @member = Member.find(params[:id])
   @timelines = []
   @timelines = @member.groups.each{|group| group.group_messages}
```

(member.rb)

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :admin, :mail, :memo, :name, :pass, :user

 has_many :friends
 has_many :messages
 has_many :comments
 has_many :group_in_members, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :groups, :through => :group_in_members
end
```

(group.rb)

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :admin, :memo, :name
 has_many :group_in_members, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :members, :through => :group_in_members
 has_many :group_messages
end
```

(group_message.rb)

```
class GroupMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content, :member_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :group
end
```

3.Errors

```
NoMethodError in Members#show

Showing /Users/******/******/****/app/views/members/show.html.erb    where line #32 raised:

undefined method `member' for #<Group:0x007fac639e2c00>
Extracted source (around line #32):

29: <div id="timeline"> 
30:  <%= @timelines.each do |tl|%>
31:   <div class="message_area">
32:   <p class= "member_name"><a href="/members/<%= tl.member %>">
33:    <%= tl.member.name %></a></p>
34:   <p class="message_content"><%= tl.content %></p>
35:   <p class="message_create">(<%= tl.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
```

Comment: Check the value of @timelines using `raise @timelines.inspect` at the top of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a classic!

you used `each` where you wanted to use `map`

```
@timelines = @member.groups.each{|group| group.group_messages}
```

so `@timelines` is the groups array, as this is the return value of each, it just returns itself.

this would have been obvious to you if you knew how to debug things properly.

a simple thing would be to use `<%= debug tl %>` or use `inspect` to find out what the current object is, that you are trying to work with.

Comment: Mr.phoet, thank you very much for your advise. I just did things like below on show.html.erb(-members)and it worked. But still I don't understand how to acquire data from the groups which this user joined. 
<h1>Mypage</h1>
<% group = Group.find(24) %>
<% group.group_messages.each do |msg| %>
<%= group.name + ": " + msg.content + ":" + msg.member.name %><br>
<% end %>

Comment: Thank you again. I used map eventually.